# zipping/merging two sorted lists

Tags: c#

i have two sorted dictionaries both with the type signature

i.e.

```
SortedDictionary<decimal, long> A
SortedDictionary<decimal, long> B
```

I want to merge the two lists where the key is the same, thus creating a new list like

```
SortedDictionary<decimal, KeyValuePair<long,long>>
or
SortedDictionary<decimal, List<long>>
```

This may not be the best way of approacing the situation but could someone give me a heads up on how to do this or a better way to approach it.

Comment: Why second is KeyValuePair ? Shoudn't be it just a List<T> ?

Comment: List would work aswell. added it in

Comment: Trying to make sure I understand what you're after -- do you want elements that are in only *one* of the initial dictionaries to appear in the output dictionary, or *only* keys that appear in both dictionaries? @Tigran - hopefully this will clear things up

Comment: @Abstract: I edited my post. **If** you don not need the keys that **are not** present on both dics, skip the code indicated.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity, i wanted the output dictionary to only contain the keys that appear in both of the dictionaries. I'm fairly sure Reniuz answered it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I've got:

```
SortedDictionary<decimal, List<long>> merged = new SortedDictionary<decimal, List<long>>
 (
   A.Union(B)
   .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => new List<long>(x))
 );
```

EDIT: Above solution selects keys not included in both collections. This should select where keys are same:

```
SortedDictionary<decimal, List<long>> merged = new SortedDictionary<decimal, List<long>>
 (
   A.Where(x=>B.ContainsKey(x.Key))
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => new List<long>(){x.Value, B[x.Key]})
 );
```

Comment: oooo I think that's a pretty clean way of approaching it! I like the .ToLookup() call better than a GroupBy -- makes for easier comprehension I think

Comment: OP should look no further for the answer:)

Comment: "I want to merge the two lists where the key is the same." Your answer includes keys that are not in both dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Another LINQ way of doing this that I think captures the intent better in terms of set operations:

```
SortedDictionary<decimal, long> a = new SortedDictionary<decimal, long>();
SortedDictionary<decimal, long> b = new SortedDictionary<decimal, long>();

a.Add(0, 10);
a.Add(1, 10);
a.Add(2, 100);
a.Add(100, 1);

b.Add(0, 4);
b.Add(4, 4);
b.Add(2, 10);

var result = a.Union(b)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => (long)y.Value).ToList());
```

Comment: This wouldn't add elements the has not the **same** key in both dictionaries.

Comment: note that I don't know if there's a requirement for the output to be a `SortedDictionary`. If so, that's not hard to remedy.

Comment: @Tigran - the OP stated 'I want to merge the two lists where the key is the same'. I took that to mean a Union

Comment: it's not about sorted or not, it's about if one dictionaru (say) has more keys then another, so there are keys in one shihc are not present in another

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it not easy:

```
Dictionary<decimal, long> dic1 = new Dictionary<decimal, long>{ {3,23}, {2,3}, {5,4}, {6,8}};
    Dictionary<decimal, long> dic2 = new Dictionary<decimal, long>{ {3,2}, {2,5}, {5,14}, {12,2}};


    //recover shared keys (the keys that are present in both dictionaries)
    var sharedKeys = dic1.Select(dic => dic.Key).Intersect(dic2.Select(d2=>d2.Key));
    sharedKeys.Dump();

    //add to the fìnal dictionary
    var final = new Dictionary<decimal, List<long>>();
    foreach(var shk in  sharedKeys) {

       if(!final.ContainsKey(shk)) 
          final[shk] = new List<long>(); 

        final[shk].Add(dic1[shk]);
        final[shk].Add(dic2[shk]);
    }

**EDIT** 
//Skip below part if you need only keys present on both dictionaries.
///-----------------------------------------------------------------

    //get unique keys present in Dic1 and add
    var nonsharedkeys1 = dic1.Select(d=>d.Key).Where(k=>!sharedKeys.Contains(k)); 
    foreach(var nshk in  nonsharedkeys1) {

        final[nshk] = new List<long>();             
        final[nshk].Add(dic1[nshk]);        
    }

     //get unique keys present in Dic2 and add
    var nonsharedkeys2 =  dic2.Select(d=>d.Key).Where(k=>!sharedKeys.Contains(k));
    foreach(var nshk in  nonsharedkeys2) {

        final[nshk] = new List<long>();             
        final[nshk].Add(dic2[nshk]);        
    }
```

*Should* work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply using LINQ:

```
var query = from a in A
            join b in B
                on a.Key equals b.Key
            select new {
                Key = a.Key,
                Value = Tuple.Create(a.Value, b.Value)
            };
var merged = new SortedDictionary<decimal, Tuple<long, long>>(
                 query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
             );
```

I think you should use `Tuple<long, long>` as your `TValue` in the merged dictionary.

Comment: your results are different than what I got with extension syntax when run with the same data. Yours produces: { {0, {10, 4}, {2, {100, 10}} }. Mine produces: { {0, {10,4}}, {1, {10}}, {2, {100,10}}, {100, {1}}, {4, {4}} } (using sample entries in my post)

Comment: wouldn't work for `list1:{{1,1}{2,2}}` and  `list2:{{2,2}{3,3}}`

Comment: @L.B: We are clearly understanding the requirements differently. On your example, mine produces `{2, (2, 2)}`. That seems consistent with the requirement "I want to merge the two lists where the key is the same." Please tell me how you are understanding it. Only one of us can be right.

Comment: I think the keyword is `where the key is the same` and you might be right. I'll cancel downvote.

Comment: @Josh E: Why are you assuming that your interpretation is right? He said "I want to merge the two lists where the key is the same." It is not clear, until we get clarification from the OP, that keys that are not in common should be included in the merged dictionary. But, I stress, he said "I want to merge the two lists where the key is the same." By not explicitly including keys that are not in common, he is implicitly excluding them. He explicitly said "**I want to merge the two lists where the key is the same**."

Comment: @Jason - you never got a downvote from me, I make no assumptions on the veracity of my answer over yours! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could "abuse" `Concat` and `Aggregate` like this:

```
var A = new SortedDictionary<decimal,long>();
var B = new SortedDictionary<decimal,long>();

A.Add(1, 11);
A.Add(2, 22);
A.Add(3, 33);

B.Add(2, 222);
B.Add(3, 333);
B.Add(4, 444);

var C = A.Concat(B).Aggregate(
    new SortedDictionary<decimal, List<long>>(),
    (result, pair) => {
        List<long> val;
        if (result.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out val))
            val.Add(pair.Value);
        else
            result.Add(pair.Key, new[] { pair.Value }.ToList());
        return result;
    }
);

foreach (var x in C)
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Format(
            "{0}:\t{1}",
            x.Key,
            string.Join(", ", x.Value)
        )
    );
```

The resulting output:

```
1:      11
2:      22, 222
3:      33, 333
4:      444
```

This is pretty much the same as if you wrote a "normal" `foreach` and would in fact work on any `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, long>>` (not just `SortedDictionary<decimal, long>`) and is easy to extend to more than two input collections if needed.

Unfortunately, it also completely disregards the fact that the input `SortedDictionary` is, well, sorted, so performance is not optimal. For optimal performance you'd have to fiddle with linearly advancing separate `IEnumerator` for each of the input sorted dictionaries, while constantly comparing the underlying elements - you could completely avoid `TryGetValue` that way...